# triangle in openGL 3.1 but nothing in 3.2

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-3

Anybody knows why this code shows a triangle in openGL 3.1 but nothing in 3.2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

GLuint myVBO;

void onDraw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

void loadData() {
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &myVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void createWindow() {
    int w=800,h=600;
    if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE){
        return;
    }
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2); //change to 1 to see the triangle
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if(!glfwOpenWindow(w,h,5,6,5,0,8,0,GLFW_WINDOW)){
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        return;
    }
    printf("Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("Error: %d\n", glGetError());
}
int main() {
    createWindow();
    loadData();
    while(1){onDraw();}
    return 0;
}
```

based on the first 2 tutorials on http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/
My output is

```
Version: 3.2.0 NVIDIA 295.49
Error: 1280
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library

Comment: Not in the glew part, glewExperimental=TRUE seems not related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply a full working set of shaders, i.e. a vertex and a fragment shader at least.

Comment: Same result with version 330 core shaders. Could it be that glew doesn't support core profile?

Answer (score 2):

Try specifically asking for a compatibility profile:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE );
```

Comment: OK, this shows the triangle, but what needs to be changed to be able to see something with GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE?

Comment: Actually using a proper core profile GL command sequence with full vertex and fragment shaders.  There are no freebies in core :)