# OpenGL 3.0 to 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl

I am in the process up upgrading my code from OpenGL 3.0 to 3.3 (or maybe even 4.x) but I am missing something, since the screen is black.

The closest answer to this problem was [triangle in openGL 3.1 but nothing in 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785801/triangle-in-opengl-3-1-but-nothing-in-3-2). The solution here is using the compatibility profile. The only hint there on implementing a proper using the core profile is "Actually using a proper core profile GL command sequence with full vertex and fragment shaders."

The problem I have is that after sinking an entire afternoon reading the spec, tutorials and examples, I don't see what my code is doing wrong. I am currently working on a demo that recycles some code I use and you can find the entire demo, currently just rendering a triangle at [gitub](https://github.com/rioki/oceandemo/tree/69f02ae1b0b79b540817e5d74452380879b1809e).

The juicy bits are the following:

The vertex code is:

```
#version 150
in vec3 aVertex;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = aVertex;
}
```

The fragment code is:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 oFragColor;

void main()
{
    oFragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);       
}
```

Compiling the shader is done as [follows](https://github.com/rioki/oceandemo/blob/69f02ae1b0b79b540817e5d74452380879b1809e/oceandemo/Shader.cpp#L44):

```
int status = 0;
char logstr[256];

const GLchar* vbuff[1] = {vertex_code.c_str()};

unsigned int vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertex_id, 1, vbuff, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex_id);

glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_id, 256, NULL, logstr);

glGetShaderiv(vertex_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if(! status)
{
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);    
    throw std::runtime_error(logstr);
}

const GLchar* fbuff[1] = {fragment_code.c_str()};

unsigned int fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragment_id, 1, fbuff, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragment_id);

glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_id, 256, NULL, logstr);

glGetShaderiv(fragment_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if(! status)
{            
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
    throw std::runtime_error(logstr);
}

program_id = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program_id, vertex_id);
glAttachShader(program_id, fragment_id);
glLinkProgram(program_id);

glGetShaderInfoLog(program_id, 256, NULL, logstr);

glGetShaderiv(program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
if(! status)
{            
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
    glDeleteProgram(program_id);
    throw std::runtime_error(logstr);
}

glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
```

The shader is bound with a simple:

```
glUseProgram(program_id);
```

The vertex buffer is created as [follows](https://github.com/rioki/oceandemo/blob/69f02ae1b0b79b540817e5d74452380879b1809e/oceandemo/Mesh.cpp#L57):

```
glGenBuffers(5, buffers);

size_t vcount = vertexes.size();
size_t fcount = faces.size();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VERTEX_BUFFER]);    
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 3 * sizeof(float), &vertexes[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[NORMAL_BUFFER]);    
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 3 * sizeof(float), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[TEXCOORD_BUFFER]);    
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 2 * sizeof(float), &texcoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[TANGENT_BUFFER]);    
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 3 * sizeof(float), &tangents[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[INDEX_BUFFER]);    
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, fcount * 3 * sizeof(unsigned int), &faces[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);  

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The vertex buffer is then rendered with the [following sequence](https://github.com/rioki/oceandemo/blob/69f02ae1b0b79b540817e5d74452380879b1809e/oceandemo/Mesh.cpp#L98):

```
int vertex_location   = shader.get_attribute_location("aVertex");
int normal_location   = shader.get_attribute_location("aNormal");
int texcoord_location = shader.get_attribute_location("aTexCoord");
int tangent_location  = shader.get_attribute_location("aTangent");

if (vertex_location != -1)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_location);
}

if (normal_location != -1)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[NORMAL_BUFFER]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normal_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normal_location);
}

if (texcoord_location != -1)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[TEXCOORD_BUFFER]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texcoord_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texcoord_location);
}

if (tangent_location != -1)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[TANGENT_BUFFER]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(tangent_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(tangent_location);
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[INDEX_BUFFER]);        
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, faces.size() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The attribute location is determined with:

```
return glGetAttribLocation(program_id, name.c_str());
```

This code works well with 3.0 and 3.1. What detail did I miss so that it breaks starting with OpenGL 3.2 core. (It obviously also works in 3.2 compat.)

Comment: From the code pasted so far, I'd say your code is lacking VAOs which are mandatory in core.

Comment: You can generate and bind a single VAO for the entire duration of your application. The difference between compatibility and core is that in core, if you don't have a non-zero VAO bound, then all commands like `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` are invalid operations. _Have you actually checked `glGetError ()`? It would be showing `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` if this is the case._

Comment: Subset of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595368/converting-glsl-modern-opengl-3-2.

Comment: Also very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643027/opengl-invalid-operation-following-glenablevertexattribarray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use VAOs

Create one with `glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);` and bind with `glBindVertexArray(vao);`

move the bining code to the setup code move like so

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
int vertex_location   = shader.get_attribute_location("aVertex");
int normal_location   = shader.get_attribute_location("aNormal");
int texcoord_location = shader.get_attribute_location("aTexCoord");
int tangent_location  = shader.get_attribute_location("aTangent");

if (vertex_location != -1)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VERTEX_BUFFER]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_location);
}

//etc.

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[INDEX_BUFFER]);  
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

then during rendering it's just

```
glBindeVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, faces.size() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindeVertexArray(0);
```

It's probably best to [bind the attribute locations](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) before linking the programs so position is always 1 and normals always 2 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, what actually solved my issue was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766864/glew-opengl-access-violation-when-using-glgenvertexarrays Since glGenVertexArrays was not loaded by glew, I assumed it did not belong to core...